# Reading a chunked HTTP JSON response behind basic authentication using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, http-authentication, chunked-encoding

With the huge number of ASP.net namespaces, classes and methods available I wonder if anyone can offer any assistance in narrowing down the ones I should pay particular attention to in order to:

*Read a chunked HTTP stream, which contains JSON data, after connecting via basic HTTP authentication, all in ASP.NET (v4.5) C#.*

Some of the classes I've been focusing on so far, albeit with not much luck, are:

- HttpClient
- HttpContent
- HttpRequestMessage
- HttpWebRequest
- HttpWebResponse
- StreamReader
- CredentialCache
- NetworkCredential

I've got a feeling I'm close, but just can't tie everything together.

Can anyone offer any help, or even a simple example?

Comment: I am doing the same thing. Any luck?